# ng-options don't apply to the select statement with the Add New function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi all Have these JSON values

`[{"Employee":{"Empid":"EF00001","Fname":"Aruna","Lname":"Jayalath"}}]`

But I cannot get the values inside the select statement when I execute this function in the angular controller.

SriptController.js

```
$scope.addNew = function (records) {

            EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
                $scope.empDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);
                console.log("Here");
            });



            $scope.records.push({

                'Empid': $scope.records.Empid,
                'Role': $scope.records.Role,
                'currAllo': $scope.records.currAllo,
                'hours': $scope.records.hours,
                'Fname': $scope.records.Fname
            });
        }
```

and HTML code:

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectemp" name="selectemp" ng-model="emp.Employee.Empid" ng-options="emp as emp.Employee.Fname for emp in empDetails track by emp.Employee.Empid">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

When I click add New function It should fill up the select option. How do I achieve this. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After push record in $scope.records you have to give all value to $scope.empDetails in JSON format.